# Output file numbering in graphicsmagick

Tags: graphicsmagick

I'm trying to convert pdf to images using this command:

```
gm convert ./file.pdf -scene 1 thumbs/thumb%02d.jpg
```

Although I specify -scene argument, it does nothing, as I get output files starting from thumb00.jpg. And I need them to start from thumb01.jpg.

I'm using GraphicsMagick 1.3.12.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to ensure numbered output files, add the +adjoin option like:

```
gm convert ./file.pdf -scene 1 +adjoin thumbs/thumb%02d.jpg
```

This additional requirement was added by GraphicsMagick 1.3.15.  It is ok to use the same option for all earlier releases.

There is still an inability to specify the starting scene number.  This is a known bug.

Comment: That's a pity, looks like I'll have to do ugly bash postprocessing then. 
Is there some public issue/ticket opened for this bug, so I could monitor if it's fixed? I can't find any mentions.